# Flink non-keyed window with parallelism greater than 1

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am consuming a Kafka topic with more than 50 partitions using FlinkKafkaConsumer(...). I would like to create windows for these partitions. However, I don't expect any shuffling, so I can't use DataStream.keyBy(...). If I call DataStream.windowAll(...), the parallelism will be 1, which also not what I expect.

So is there any ways I can keep the high value of parallelism and no data shuffling at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using keyBy, your options become rather limited. You could implement some sort of parallel windowing with a (non-keyed) `ProcessFunction`, but you won't have access to timers or keyed state, just [operator state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#using-operator-state).